# Calling objects into an ArrayList in class PurseMain

Tags: java, arraylist

Okay, the objective of this program is to input String values, such as penny, dime, quarter, and nickel, into the ArrayList purse in class Purse. Then once Purse is executed through the PurseMain class then the Coin class is supposed to take the string values of the coin names that were added into the ArrayList purse and add their dollar values together. My professor told us to create the coin values in a third Class called Coin and to create another ArrayList in PurseMain. But really my main question is, how do you call the objects that were created in the Coin Class into the ArrayList in PurseMain? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
package purse;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;



/**
* The Purse program creates an ArrayList called purse that gets printed out,
 reversed, and transfered into another ArrayList called purse2. 
 *     
 *               - ArrayList purse 
 *               - ArrayList purse2
 *               - Scanner coin - the Scanner that is used to type the                             contents of ArrayList purse
 *               - Scanner coin2- the Scanner that is used to type the  contents of ArrayList purse2
 *               - String input - contains Scanner coin and is used to fill    ArrayList purse
 *               - String input2- contains Scanner coin2 and is used to fill  ArrayList purse2
 *               - String end - sentinel for ending the process inputting    strings into Scanner coin and Scanner coin2
 *      
 */
public class Purse  
{ 
  ArrayList<String> purse = new ArrayList<>(); 


   /**
   *  fills ArrayList purse and purse2 with U.S coin names 
   *  purse gets printed out and then again is printed in reverse
   *  purse2 is printed

   */

  public void addCoin()
  { 



   String penny = "penny";
   String nickel = "nickel";
  String dime = "dime";
  String quarter = "quarter";
  String end = "done";

  Scanner coin = new Scanner (System.in); 
   String input = " ";
  System.out.println("Please put as many coins of U.S currency as you like into the purse, hit the ENTER button after each coin and, type 'done' when finished: ");

  while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase ("done"))
  {  input = ( coin.nextLine());
   if   (input.equalsIgnoreCase("penny")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("nickel")||input.equals IgnoreCase("dime")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("quarter")||input.equalsIgnoreCase(en d))
   {
        purse.add(input);
        purse.remove(end);
    }
   else{
       System.out.println("Please input a coin of U.S currency.");
    }
    }
  }

  /**
  @return ArrayList purse
  */
 public ArrayList<String> printPurseContents()
  { 
      System.out.println("Contents of the purse: " + purse);
      return purse;  
  }

     /** checks whether purse2 has the same coins in the same order as purse
     * @return 
     * @param purse2
   */



  public boolean sameContents(Purse purse2)
  {

      if (purse2.purse.equals(purse)) 
      {
          return true; 
  } 
  else
  {
      return false;
  }   

 }
  /**
  * checks whether purse2 has the same coins as in purse, disregarding the  order
  * @param purse2
  * @return 
 */

 public boolean sameCoins(Purse purse2) 
{

   if( purse2.purse.containsAll(purse))
  {
      return true; 
  }    
    else
  {
     return false;
  }
 } 


/**
* adds contents of purse into purse2 and clears purse of its contents
 * @param purse2    
*/
public void transfer(Purse purse2)  
{
           purse2.purse.addAll(purse);
            purse.clear();

 System.out.println("The second purse now has: " + purse2.purse );
 System.out.println("and the first purse has: " + purse);


 }


}
```

----------PurseMain

```
package purse;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project  Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

 /**legalcoin = new ArrayList<Coin>; <-----
 * legalcoin.add( new Coin ("Penny", .01); <--- Professor said to do
 *
 * @author 
 * 9/01/2015
 * Lab I 
 */
public class PurseMain 
 {

  private ArrayList<Coin> legalCoin = new ArrayList<>();
  legalCoin.add (new Coin ("Penny",0.01));

 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Purse purse1 = new Purse();
  purse1.addCoin();
  purse1.printPurseContents();
    Purse purse2 = new Purse();
  purse2.addCoin();
  purse2.printPurseContents();
 System.out.println("Both of the purses have the same contents and the contents is in the same order: " + purse2.sameContents(purse1));
 System.out.println("Both of the purses have the same contents: "  +purse2.sameCoins(purse1));



    }
}
```

----------Coin

```
 package purse;

/*
   * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
  */

  /** private string name;
     * private double value;
     * sum up value method
     *
      * @author
  */
 public class Coin 
{

   private String Penny = "penny";
   private String Nickel = "nickel";
   private String Dime = "dime";
   private String Quarter = "quarter";
   private double penny = 0.01;
   private double nickel = 0.05;
   private double dime = 0.10;
   private double quarter = 0.25;    

   public void SumUpValue()
   {

   }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a new Coin pouch in your purse(requirement wise). So, have a coin pouch that takes list of coins in it. Since the purse has the coin pouch, it would be a property of your purse.

```
public class Coin{
   private String type;
   private String currencyType;
//more fields and getters and setters
}

public class Purse{  

  ArrayList<String> purse = new ArrayList<>(); 
  List<Coins> coinPouch = new ArrayList<>();//contains coin objects
.
.
.
.

   private void addCoins(String coinType){
      Coin coin = new Coin();
      coin.setType(coinType);

      coinPouch.add(coin);
   }
}
```

Your modified code for adding coins would be like:

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("penny")|| input.equalsIgnoreCase("nickel")  ||input.equalsIgnoreCase("dime")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("quarter")||input.equalsIgnoreCase(end)){
   addCoins(input);//Adds coins to the list of coins objects and the purse now has the coin pouch :D
   purse.remove(end);
}
else{
   System.out.println("Please input a coin of U.S currency.");
}
```

Comment: Okay, I mostly understand what you're doing, but where does setType come from? Did you create another method or class somewhere or is it called from the Java Library? Other than that though I understand.

Comment: The Coin class has a property type which I have given. I have added a comment that says-//more fields and getters and setters . I didn't add the setter method for the property as it would make code lengthy. You add the setter method and getter method.

Comment: Consider marking answer as closed/vote if it gives what you wanted. Thanks.